# Get page feed with Facebook API Graph in Python

Tags: python, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, request

I'm trying to fetch facebook page information and feed/posts, and specifically the text of each post.
I've registered a new test app, on Facebook for Developers, and I get client token, secret token and ID. I've not inserted any privacy link or Terms of Use link because it is a personal test.
In the Graph API Explorer I get the app access token, and I'm using it.
Using facebook-sdk I can get pages information via the following code:

```
accessToken = "xxx"
user = 'BillGates'

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(accessToken, version='2.7')

profile = graph.get_object(id=user, fields='id,name,about,link,location,hometown,website', limit=100)
```

So far, no problem. Now, I would want to get posts with this code:

```
posts = graph.get_connections(profile['id'], connection_name='posts', fields='caption,created_time,description,from,link,message,object_id,parent_id,permalink_url,picture,privacy,place,properties,shares,source,status_type,story,to,type,with_tags', limit='100')
```

or making a `request.get()` at this url:

```
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/BillGates?fields=feed{caption,created_time,description,from,link,message,object_id,parent_id,permalink_url,picture,source,status_type,type}&limit=100&access_token=xxx"
```

but I receive this error:

```
facebook.GraphAPIError: (#15) Requires session when calling from a desktop app
```

My app has the contact email, is a native or computer application (it will run on a linux server), is public and has just email, public_profile and user_friend as approved elements. Other elements can't be approved because I've to fill notes, but I'm unable to fill them.

My idea is to request, periodically, a "general" access token, or an access token for each page I've to analyze.

Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: FYI: The “Native or desktop app” settings is for apps that need to embed the app secret in client-side code. If you have an app running on your server, you should not set this to Yes.

Comment: Resolved setting "Native or desktop app" to No. Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been solve by using {client_access_token} as access_token

```
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/#{fb_id}/apprequests/?access_token=#{client_access_token}"
```